# Local javascript cannot open local file

Tags: javascript, ajax

Please tell me, why local javascript cannot open a local file?
I'm trying to create a simple javascript/html app that shall run on the local machine from local filesystem. This app is trying to read the configuration file (json) using different methods, but gets the following errors (Chrome):

1. In case of XMLHttpRequest, method `open("GET", filename, true)` throws an exception:

   > XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///bla-bla-bla. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
2. In case of `document.createElement("iframe").src=filename` I have another exception:

   > VM596:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame."
3. In case of `var f=new File([], filename, { type: "text/plain" });` I've got the File object with the zero size and no errors at all. FileReader returns an empty result then.

So, my questions are: 
Why is it "cross-origin"? These files are stored in the same directory!
And how could I open the local file from the same origin/directory I run the script?
Please help.

P.S.: Yes, I know about `--allow-file-access-from-files` but I need to run this by customers.

Comment: The `file://` protocol really has a very limited usage oriented for testing or viewing one individual file. For true webapp testing, you'll want to set up a small, basic "web server" program which can take requests to `localhost/index.html` or `localhost/bla-bla-bla.js`. Python, for instance, lets you set one up in the current folder via command line with `python -m SimpleHttpServer 80`

Comment: @BbIKTOP, tou can transform the JSON file into a javascript file (add `var myVariable = ` to the start of the json file) and then include it using `<script src='myfile.js'></script>` the data will be in `myVariable` (object). Not the best solution though but works.

Comment: They have more that 100 pcs without LAN, running very specific software (gym) and this app is intended to show some advert videoclips. 
Thats why it is not possible to use such an obvious solution with the webserver an that's why I'm asking here about that.

Sure, it is possible not to use a json configuration but put the config into the code, maybe in the separate file. It's not interesting and there's no need to ask nor discuss it here.

Comment: it's how chrome does things, google has declared it so, and therefore there is nothing you can do about it, short of creating a web extension ... Use firefox, or edge, or internet ex... not, don't use that!

Comment: There's absolutely no difference as far as deployment, update or runtime functionality between using a script tag vs xhr ... as for the iframe issue, the code you showed would be pointless, as you've created an iframe that you have "lost" access to, so there's no way to add it to the DOM

Comment: I just tried different ways that, as I can imagine, could work. Spent about half an hour without any success and asked here.
Ok, so it is not possible. Will create a script with this flag then and will tell them to run it.
Thank you!

Comment: @BbIKTOP Sorry I'm noticing this late, but it should be noted that a computer off of any network can still connect to `localhost`. If they cannot have programs installed then it's still an issue, but just making sure you weren't avoiding it for the wrong reasons.

Comment: Yes, it surely could be done using any kind of server, and I even can make this simple server on plain C or to use any existing. But the question is, is it possible to achieve using local js/css/html without installing any special software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do to read your .json file, is to declare it a .js.

**data.js**

```
var data = `{"value1": 10, "value2": "hello"}`
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="data.js"></script>

<script>
  console.log(JSON.parse(data))
</script>
```

This will print

```
Object {value1: 10, value2: "hello"}
```

Both of them have to be in the same directory, otherwise you've to change the import of data.js.

Comment: Why, I could put it in the same file then, why do I need to use data.js?
Just as simple as 
'<script>
var data='{"v1": 1, "v2": 2}';
</script>
'

Comment: @BbIKTOP  So you keep your data separated from your source code. The idea is to use data.js as an hypothetical data.json. If you have to change "v2" value to 3, you can without have to open your source code.

Answer (score 5):

> Why is it "cross-origin"? These files are stored in the same directory!

Because Chrome considers **all** `file://` URLs to be cross-origin to each other.

> And how could I open the local file from the same origin/directory I run the script?

From Chrome? You don't. Not unless you disable CORS entirely with a command-line option (which is a bad idea, as it's trivially easy to forget you've set that command-line option and go surf the web, leaving yourself wide open to exploits cashing in on the fact you've disabled web security).

Other browsers may treat origin `null` differently.

Instead, run a local web server and make the files available via the local web server. Then you can access them because it'll be a same-origin `http` URL, not a `file` URL. Or use any of the dozen or so frameworks that let you write apps in JavaScript (rather than using the browser). Or a simple NodeJS script serving the files (it's about 10 lines long). Etc.

Comment: All "file" are crossorigins? Very smart and clever design )))))))

So, there's no way to make such an application?

Sure, I do have a server and understand how to do that with the server, it's so simple, but the question was, is it possible to achieve that without it. It is unreal to install the web server on any embedded pc they need to run this crap. And these pcs ain't connected to the network at all.

Comment: @BbIKTOP: I answered that question: You can't. (And swearing is not okay on Stack Overflow.) Use any of the several "make an app with JavaScript" solutions instead. Make your system use Node. Or any of a dozen other similar solutions.

Comment: @BbIKTOP The fact the PC isn't connected to a network is irrelevant. The idea is to run an embedded web server for the duration of your application process. It should stop serving when the application closes because it's part of the application not another server somewhere else on the network. You would use a port other than 80 because you aren't really trying to serve to the internet. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001185/what-is-the-recommended-way-of-running-a-embedded-web-server-within-a-desktop-ap

Comment: @t-j-crowder You said that I could install a server. Of course I know that I can! )))))) Just write clearly "It is not possible" and this will be a great answer then

Comment: @ThisClark Do you really think that installing the webserver on over that 100 embedded pcs to run a promo video is a good idea? )))))))))

Comment: @BbIKTOP: From the answer: *"'And how could I open the local file from the same origin/directory I run the script?' From Chrome? **You don't**"*

Comment: Yes, I meant the rest of the lyrics about servers etc.

Comment: @BbIKTOP: Re your edit: I said "Chrome," specifically, *for a reason*. Different browsers may handle origin `null` differently. I've fixed it.

Comment: you'd rather delete the story about a local servers then.
What browsers do support it?

Comment: @BbIKTOP: I haven't tried lately. Last I checked, Firefox did.

Comment: well, will put it in the code. Not good but will work at least. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A little late for this party, but I had the same issue and this was how I got around the problem

Create a js template such as this:

**template.js**

```
(function(global, factory) {
    "use strict";
    factory(global);
})(typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this, function(window) {
    "use strict";
    var myObjectJson = '<JSONREPLACE>';
    var myObject = JSON.parse(myObjectJson);
    window.myObject = myObject;
});
```

Then, have your json replace the  tag either by your program that could generate the exported js itself, or create a batch script file that does that for you. I'm using C# so I just build the template directly from there. If the language you're working on is half-decent, you should be able to generate and export your file.

Make sure you use a minified json string.

Then you use your generated file just like you'd use jQuery

```
<script src="generated.js"></script>
```

and access your object with

```
window.myObject;
```

It's slightly more complicated to set-up, but once you do, you completely remove the cross-origin issue.